# SwiftUI ViewBuilder and non-sendable type 'Binding<Bool>' in a `@Sendable` closure

Tags: swift, swiftui, viewbuilder

I have a `ViewBuilder` that I use to lock/unlock some views. It uses a `Binding` to pass the locked/unlocked `State`.

I am now getting this warning on the `if` line:

> Capture of 'isUnlocked' with non-sendable type 'Binding' in a
> `@Sendable` closure

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func requestUnlock(isUnlocked: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        
        self.task {
            if isUnlocked.wrappedValue == false {
                let unlocked = await Unlock.authenticate()
                isUnlocked.wrappedValue = unlocked
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As this is an extension of `View` I cannot add or ignore `Sendable` compliance and i'm not sure what magic is needed for me to clear this warning.

Comment: It's currently set to minimum, this warning creeped in with Xcode 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a view modifier instead and let SwiftUI handle the updates and actor isolation for you via the property wrapper:

```swift
struct UnlockRequester: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isUnlocked: Bool
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.task {
            if isUnlocked == false {
                isUnlocked = await Unlock.authenticate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
extension View {
    func requestUnlock(isUnlocked: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        self.modifier(UnlockRequester(isUnlocked: isUnlocked))
    }
}
```

This gives no warnings even with strict concurrency checking enabled.